# Convert A weighted voltage output into sound pressure

Tags: amplifier, sound

I have designed an A weighting network circuit. but i cant understand how to convert it's voltage output in to corresponding sound pressure level in dB. So How can I convert these voltage readings into dB?

Comment: Perhaps with a logarithmic amplifier.

Comment: OP, please wait before accepting an answer, I feel mine can be expanded quite a lot and there are probably people who will be able to provide a better insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your output is also driving an amplifier and then some loudspeakers.

If that's the case the best way to calibrate your [vu meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter) is put some pure tone in the amp and measure the spl with a microphone [nicely placed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker_measurement).

You can also search for a parameter called "sensitivity", the manufacturer of your loudspeakers should be able to tell you it. Sensitivity is measured in \$\frac{\text{dB}}{\text{W}\cdot\text{m}}\$, i.e. is the spl in decibel the loudspeaker outputs for each watt of power you give to it, measured at a distance of 1m. Problem is that [sensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker#Specifications) depends on frequency and on the enclosing and probably other parameters.

Comment: +1, since different speakers will have different efficiency; some speakers will generate nearly no sound at a given drive voltage, while other speakers may generate quite a lot of sound with exactly the same drive.

Comment: and that's why a 15W Marshall high end amp can blow out any 100W "Hi-Fi" system